# How to select a random image from a folder for CNN test process?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I would like to ask if there is any way for my codes to select an image randomly from a folder containing a lot of fruit images. The idea is to test my CNN model using a random image. Here is my code that I've tried but there is an error as shown below.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import os
import random

test_img  = random.choice(os.listdir("drive/My Drive/HAZIQ/TESTTEST/MODELTEST/"))
img = image.load_img(test_img, target_size = (208,256))
img = image.img_to_array(img, dtype=np.uint8)
img = np.array(img)/255.0
prediction = model.predict(img[np.newaxis, ...])

print("Probability: ",np.max(prediction[0], axis=-1))
predicted_class = class_names[np.argmax(prediction[0], axis=-1)]
print("Classified: ",predicted_class,'\n')

plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(img.squeeze())
plt.title("Loaded Image")
```

THE ERROR

> FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call > last)  in () > 5 > 6 test_img = random.choice(os.listdir("drive/My Drive/HAZIQ/TESTTEST/MODELTEST/")) > ----> 7 img = image.load_img(test_img, target_size = (208,256)) > 8 img = image.img_to_array(img, dtype=np.uint8) > 9 img = np.array(img)/255.0 1 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py > in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation) > 111 raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. ' > 112 'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.') > --> 113 with open(path, 'rb') as f: > 114 img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read())) > 115 if color_mode == 'grayscale': FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '32660-3194-5469.jpg'

I can confirm that '32660-3194-5469.jpg' is in the folder. I don't know why it says No such file or directory.

I want it to be like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ww1Vu.png)

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code

```
os.listdir("drive/My Drive/HAZIQ/TESTTEST/MODELTEST/")
```

will return a file name but NOT the full path to the file and consequently it is not found. What you need to do is

```
sdir=r'drive/My Drive/HAZIQ/TESTTEST/MODELTEST/'
flist=os.listdir(sdir)
test_img=random.choice(flist)
test_img=os.path.join(sdir, test_img)
```

Answer (score 1):

The command `os.listdir(mydir)` returns a list containing the names of the **entries** in the directory.

1. before randomly choosing one element in the list, you must ensure that this element is actually an image file `myimage`
2. **Your problem is here** : importantly, you must set the full path : `myfilepath = os.path.join(mydir, myimage)`

alternatively you can use `glob`, which allows wildcards, let's say for jpeg images :

```
import glob
image_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(mydir, '*.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Introduce you that dataset is more suitable to convert of pre-processing data nad transform for next processes.

**[ Sample ]:**

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
DataSet
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(tf.cast(list_file, dtype=tf.int64), shape=(33, 1, 32, 32, 4), dtype=tf.int64),tf.constant(list_label, shape=(33, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(33)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(10, reshuffle_each_iteration=True)
```